# Converting Google Sheets formula to arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I have to convert a simple formula in google sheets to arrayformula, but I cannot figure out how.
Sample data:
|    P     | A | B | C | D | E |
| -------- | - | - | - | - | - |
| *string* | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 6 |
| *string* | 10| 11| 16| 0 | 37|
| *string* | 10| 3 | 6 | 0 | 19|
| *string* | 5 | 7 | 28| 0 | 40|

Formula goes in column E.
The current formula is:
`=IF(P2="","",SUM(A2:D2))`

I am trying to do the obvious conversion like this:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(P2:P="","",SUM((A2:A):(D2:D))))`

This just gives me N/A in every cell down the sheet.

Not sure why the table above is not showing as a table. Adding screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

UPDATE: [Minimal example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D93xcjMXy6BEEmaTgXCEJaVIifqW86C6JHce2U8gKZU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet? try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GabrielCarballo Here is a minimal example. I hope this helps. I am trying to convert the formula in cell F2 to an arrayformula so that it spans down the column: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D93xcjMXy6BEEmaTgXCEJaVIifqW86C6JHce2U8gKZU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",mmult(B2:E*1, transpose(B2:E2 ^ 0))))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I was eventually able to get it done in a stupider way:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",((B2:B)+(C2:C)+(D2:D)+(E2:E))))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's nothing below your table, the following in F2 should give you the sum per row for as many rows are present. It assumes that you will only ever be summing columns B:E.

```
=mmult(B2:indirect("E"&counta(A2:A)+1),sequence(counta(A2:A),1,1,0))
```

N.B - this isn't the only way of doing this.

**EDIT**
Rethinking this, given the dependence on column P and the large number of rows (and again assuming that you only ever want to sum columns B:E), why not use a simple array addition?

```
=arrayformula(if(len(P2:P),B2:B+C2:C+D2:D+E2:E,))
```

This should give a row sum for each row where the cell in column P is not empty.

Comment: This only works for me when there are four rows - should it be something like =mmult(A2:indirect("d"&counta(A2:A)+1),sequence(columns(A2:D),1,1,0))

Comment: This does not really work for me due to two reasons:
1. It does not account for the IF statement (if cell in P is empty)
2. The table has almost 4000 rows

Comment: @Tom Sharpe: Ah, yes - my mistake.